# Plotting curves of different orders of magnitudes on the same graph

Tags: plotting, visualization

I want to plot

```
Plot[{Exp[x],Sin[x]},{x,0,10}]
```

The issue is that `Sin[x]` and `Exp[x]` are not of the same order of magnitude, so we do not see `Sin[x]`. Therefore, I would like to set different y-axis but on the same graph. For `Exp[x]`, the `y` axis would go from 0 to 25000 and for `Sin[x]` from -1 to 1. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why do you need to plot curves with widely-varying ranges together?

Comment: I have a case when I want to visualize the data and the log of the data. The curve is supposed to be an exponential at the beginning and vary linearly at the end. I want to see a linear evolution at the beginning with the log of the data, a linear evolution at the end with the data, and a transition area. I asked my question in a simple way, since the data is pretty big and that it's a general question

Comment: How about `LogPlot`?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ:  That won't work so well for a function that becomes negative, like `Sin[x]` does.  (There are ways around this, of course.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Actually, it is about data rescaling. Admittedly, log function is not "good at" dealing with non-positive values, but it is not difficult to find a proper rescaling function to use.

Comment: You really shouldn't plot them within the same frame unless you want to confuse your readers. If I were a referee of your paper, I would complain. Use two vertically stacked plots with an aligned horizontal axis.

Comment: It's a not an article, don't worry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rescaling the y-coordinates:

```
rescaleShow[p1_, p2_] := Module[{g1, g2, pr1, pr2, rs1, rs2},
   {g1, g2} = Cases[{p1, p2}, _Graphics, Infinity];
   {pr1, pr2} = Last /@ PlotRange /@ {g1, g2};
   rs1 = With[{pr = Last@PlotRange[g1]}, Rescale[#, pr] &];
   rs2 = With[{pr = Last@PlotRange[g2]}, Rescale[#, pr] &];
   Show[
    p1 /. Line[p_] :> Line[Transpose@MapAt[rs1, Transpose@p, 2]],
    p2 /. Line[p_] :> Line[Transpose@MapAt[rs2, Transpose@p, 2]],
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks -> {{Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, pr1], 
       Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, pr2]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}
    ]
   ];
```

OP's example:

```
rescaleShow[
 Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1], PlotLegends -> {HoldForm@Exp[x]}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2], PlotLegends -> {Sin[x]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This method uses `Plot` so you get the `Plot` bells and whistles, like discontinuity processing, except for automatic coloring of the graphs:

```
rescaleShow[
 Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1], PlotLegends -> {Tan[x]}, 
  Frame -> True],
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2], PlotLegends -> {Sin[x]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 13):

A slightly modified version using `Overlay`.

```
combine[data1_, data2_] := Overlay[{ListLinePlot[data1,
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x1", "y1"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Blue], 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {40, 40}}],
  ListLinePlot[data2, Frame -> {False, False, True, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> All, FrameLabel -> {{None, "y2"}, {None, "x2"}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Red], PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {40, 40}}]}, 
 Alignment -> Center]

data1 = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.01}];
data2 = Table[{x, Exp[x]}, {x, -5, 5, 0.01}];
combine[data1, data2]
```

[image]

One advantage here is that you can use any range for x and y.

You can use `Plot` as well in the `combine` and modify the appearance.

Comment: +1 for the coding ingenuity, but honestly, for me this just reinforces the idea that a [small multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple) chart is often the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

Multiply, `Sin[x]` by, say, 1000 and rescale the right axis:

```
Plot[{Exp[x], 1000 Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{-1000, 1000}, {-1, 1}]}, 
    {Automatic, Automatic}},
  PlotLegends -> {HoldForm @ Exp[x], Sin[x]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not to nitpick, but both curves use the left axis (according to the legend).

Comment: thank you @AndreasRejbrand; good catch. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

We could also use [MultiaxisArrangement](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiaxisArrangement.html), which came with V 13.0.
It needs, however, a list as input.

```
list = Transpose @ Table[{Exp[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];

Legended[
 ListLinePlot[list,
  MultiaxisArrangement -> All],
 LineLegend[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], {"Exp", "Sin"}]]
```

[image]

Thanks, Daniel, for pointing us to `MultipleAxesPlot`:

```
ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesPlot"][
 {Exp[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10},
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> {"exp(x)", "sin(x)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Or `ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesPlot"]`

Comment: Thank you, very useful, added it to the answer.